Issue with flow of Einstein Discovery Action
Customer has created a model and they are using that in flow of Einstein Discovery Action. So they are trying to give the Manually assign variables in the Top predictors.
But by doing so the flow is throwing an error as below :  When the StoreOutputAutomatically field is set to "False", the test.topPredictors reference isn't supported.
I would like to understand that if this is possible ?
If yes could you please help me to understand how to pass variable to feild and to understand the reason of the error.
I would like to understand that if this is possible ?
If yes could you please help me to understand how to pass variable to feild and to understand the reason of the error.
error msg
setup
